# When inserting a statement, the duplicate entry is reported, but the data is not found according to the query

Tags: mysql

```
select * from XXX where image_uuid = 'XXX' and model_version_id=1;
```

[image: 1]

```
REPLACE into XXX
(image_uuid, model_version_id,description,create_time,update_time,feature_data )
values ( "XXX",1,"",CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"XXX" );
```

[image: 2]

unique index is "image_uuid,model_version_id"

According to the query results，data can be inserted

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE. it seems that the structure contains more than one unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, because the trigger is used.
A unique primary key violation occurred when inserting the statement into the new table